# A place in the proof of the snake lemma is not evident to me. Can someone please clarify?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

This place in the proof of the snake lemma is not evident to me. Can someone please clarify it?

[image]

Comment: Let $x ∈ \ker(f')$. There is a $y ∈ A'$ such that $ν'(y) = x$, and we have $f(y) = f'(ν'(y)) = 0$, so $y ∈ \ker(f)$. So $\ker(f) → \ker(f')$ is epimorphic.